# collection radio buttons customization rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in a form:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :address_id, @address_book, :id, :full_address do |b| %>
      <div class="radio">
        <%= b.label do %>
          <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

address contains lots of attributes which I dont think putting it in one class method `full_address` inside the model is good idea. designers wont be able to style this directly inside the template.

I want to be able to access each attribute in the template like so

`address.first_name` ,`address.last_name` when rendering radio buttons

is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: So you have 1 field called `full_address` and you want to split it? Do you have any delimiters in the full address like commas?

Comment: no , `full_address` is what will be shown next to the radio button. it is a call to a method `full_address` inside  `Address` model. check the docs [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons)

Comment: Yeah but what do you want to show?